# minor hairline crack on the base of a toilet, should I repair / replace?

Tags: toilet, plumbing-fixture

It was my first time removing a toilet, and when I put it back, I fastened the bolt a little too tight and heard a slight crack. I'm wondering if this is something that needs immediate attention, or if it may be fine over the long run? Nothing is leaking at this point.

[image: hairline crack at base of toilet]

Comment: hard to say. it might get worse, it might not. it doesn't look like extending the crack would compromise the seals; it looks more like just the "flap" is in trouble, but ceramic can have internal inconsistencies that alter the trajectory. i would wait it out if you can live with the appearance and it's still working ok.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace that toilet.  Sorry.  This thing will come apart.  You might be able to save the tank and just replace the bowl. But you will have to purchase the same manufacturer and a model that is compatible.

Comment: I would say it is a good opportunity to upgrade if you want.